# Variable bug(s) O'Reilly Programming PyTorch

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

I'm reading O'Reilly's Sept, 2019 publication 'Programming Pytorch ..' describing a simple linear neural network for image classification.

There is a bug in a variable name in the opening model (no worries) `target` vs. `targets`, however there is what appears to be a weird omission of a variable declaration, `train_iterator` (and also `dev_iterator`, not shown).

I wish to know is what was the `train_iterator` variable they (I presume) intended?

p27

```
def train(model, optimiser, loss_fn, train_loader, val_loader, epochs=20, device='cpu'):
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        training_loss = 0.0
        valid_loss = 0.0
        model.train()
        for batch in train_loader:
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            inputs, target = batch # Bug here for 'target'
            inputs = inputs.to(device)
            target = targets.to(device)
            output = model(inputs)
            loss = loss_fin(output, target)
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
            training_loss += loss.data.item()
        training_loss /= len(train_iterator) # What is train_iterator?
```

so,..

```
    inputs, target = batch
```

must be

```
    inputs, targets = batch
```

In the validation step below the training step (not shown) is

```
    inputs, targets = batch
    ...
    targets = targets.to(device)
```

Its no biggie and the code is simply assigning to Cudas (GPU) or CPU.

The variable `train_iterator` is defining the training loss (important diagnostic). I assume that there should be an iterator declared between the epoch and the batch iterator, or is this within the training loop?

**Notes** `train_loader` simply refers Pytorch Dataloader. The model refers to 3 linear layers with a ReLU activation function.

Comment: it should probably be `len(train_loader)`

Comment: Thanks, I considered that. It makes send but that means train_loader its just how is that associated with iteration, because it is always a constant. Bad variable name?

Comment: 'more sinister is that ' ... wait no... sorry that is my bug. Apologies and now corrected

Comment: Its probably a bug. It's possible to create an iterator of the `train_loader` instead of creating it implicitly using a for loop. If i had to speculate they had originally iterated with an explicit iterator and changed it later but then didn't test the code.

Comment: These are quite grave errors for a book that's intended for beginners. Do notify the authors or the publisher of these mistakes so that it can be fixed in a reprit!

Comment: @jodag Thanks for your insight. I guess its the editing.

Comment: I would recommend reading the [official pytorch tutorials](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/), they do a good job of explaining how things are intended to be done in pytorch. There are some good real examples too, like the [image net example](https://github.com/pytorch/examples/blob/master/imagenet/main.py) which i often use as a template if I'm in a hurry.

Comment: @jodag ... definitely, thanks.

Comment: @BramVanroy thanks I've done it and emailed bookquestions@oreilly.com together with the link to this post. I hope the author responds to this thread.